# Adding md5 hash value to mongo collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hash, mongoose, md5

**Issue:**  I currently have a mongo collection with 100,000 documents.  Each document has 3 fields (_id, name, age).  I want to add a 4th field to each document called hashValue that stores the md5 hash value of each documents name field.

I currently can interact with my collection via the mongo shell or via Mongoose ODM as part of a nodeJS app.

Possible Solutions:

1. Use Mongoose/nodeJs:

I realize this won't work (don't believe you can iterate through a cursor in this manner), but hopefully it shows what I'm trying to do.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

    MyCollection.find().forEach(function(el){
        var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(el.name).digest("hex");
        el.name = hash;
        el.save()
    });
```

2. Use mongo Shell - Almost same as above, and I realize something like the above syntax would work.  Only issue is that I don't know how to create the md5 hash in the mongo shell. But I am able to iterate through each document and add a field.
3. (possible workaround) - The goal of this is to be able to query based off the md5 hash of a name value.  I believe mongo allows you to create a hashed index ([link here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/)).  Only issue is that I can't find an example of anyone using this for querying (only seems to be used for sharding) and I'm not sure if that will work later on.  (Example: I want to md5 hash a name I collect from a user, and then query my mongo collection to see if I can find that md5 hash in the hashValue field)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Javascript already  has md5 hash function called hex_md5. Its available in mongo console as well.

```
> hex_md5('john')
527bd5b5d689e2c32ae974c6229ff785
```

So to update records in your case you can use the following code snippet in mongo console:

```
db.collection.find().forEach( function(data){
  data.hashValue = hex_md5(data.name);
  db.collection.save(data);
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly for updates in the mongo console.  See answer below if updates need to be made in mongoose.

Comment: In the latest versions, I think hex_md5 is not avaialble. I am not able to find the alternative yet. I can see MD5 class defined in the shell, but not able to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through cursor in mongoose using [streams](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/querystream.html) and update all the records using [bulk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/).

```
mongoose.connection.on("open", function(err,conn) {
    var bulk = MyCollection.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    MyCollection.find().stream()
        .on('data', function(el){
            var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(el.name).digest("hex");
            // add document update operation to a bulk
            bulk.find({'_id': el._id}).update({$set: {name: hash}});
        })
        .on('error', function(err){
            // handle error
        })
        .on('end', function(){
            // execute all bulk operations
            bulk.execute(function (error) {
                // final callback
                callback();                   
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I read the documentation and this seems to be on the right track.  bulk.find({'_id': el._id}).update({$set: {name: hash}}); returns an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined". But overall this path is a good documented solution to have here.

Comment: Fixed that error. We need to establish connection first.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not prefer to go with option 3 (i.e., Possible workaround). Tow reasons - 
1. When querying the data we have to make sure that application uses the same hash function and in the same way, as that of Mongo DB, to derive the hash value. I think Mongo DB uses MD5 and considers only the first 64 bits of hash. The disadvantage I see is the application gets tied to the internal implementation of Mongo DB hashing and could change at any point.

2. Hashed Indexes are good for point queries (equality queries). But they don't support range queries (age >  & age > 50), like or regex queries (db.users.find({"name": /ABC/}).

One thing that is not clear is why do you want store MD5 of the name column instead of creating normal index on name column itself. May be that will help in arriving at the answer.

Comment: Great question and agreed on option 3.  The reason is that I'm trying to find a way of doing efficient text search on the name field.  And because the name field can have multiple parts of a name (first, middle, last) most solutions required multiple queries, a change in the collection data structure, or inefficient regex queries.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (version 7) you can use hex_md5 inside [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) aggregation:

```
$addFields: {
  _md5: {
    $function: {
      body: function(token1, currency) {
        return hex_md5(token1 + "_" + currency);
      },
      args: ["$_token1", "$_currency"],
      lang: "js"
    }
  },
}
```